# Sharepoint refinement xml to json

Tags: .net, xml, json, sharepoint, serialization

I want to convert refinement xml to json. I tried this:

```
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            var refinementManager = RefinementManager.GetInstance(Page);
            var xmlDocument = refinementManager.GetRefinementXml();

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms, xmlDocument);
            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        }
```

but i get the error:

```
Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
```

Is there any was to convert this xml to json ?
I found JSON.net (http://json.codeplex.com/ ) is this a reliable lib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize .net object to json as following: http://www.spsamples.com/2012/02/serialize-net-objects-to-and-from-json.html
I don't know if you can serialize xml straight to json, but you can serialize xml to object and object to json.